# Support for POST data in javascript

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest

Are there any libraries that support creation of the post data for XMLHTTPRequest
in javascript.
consider the sending of post data as follows.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

[Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest)

I am wondering if there is a better way to assembling the data in the form(as opposed to string concatenation).

`var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";`

Comment: Well in the end you are going to have to make it a string... There are multiple ways to build the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `JQuery.param()`? See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/.

```
var params = { 
   lorem:ipsum, 
   name:binny 
};
var str = jQuery.param( params );
// str = lorem=ipsum&name=binny
```

Another, this time, vanilla JavaScript solution would come from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object/1714899#1714899).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [qwest](https://github.com/pyrsmk/qwest) simple, efficient and weights only 8.5K