# NodeJS GET request not working with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have this web app that is for sharing photos.

Now I have this route that is supposed to return the photos of all the users from the following array.

Route:

```
router.get('/getphotos',function(req, res){
    var reqPhotos = [];
    console.log( "\n" + req.body.username + "\n");
    try{
      for(x =0; x < req.body.following.length;  x++){
        reqPhotos.push({username: req.body.following[x].username});
      }
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }

    Photo.find({username: reqPhotos}).exec(function(err, allPhotos){
        if(err){console.log(err);}
        else{
          res.json(allPhotos);
        }
   });

});
```

I have found out that the req.body.following was undefined. This is how I was calling it using angular:

```
$scope.getPhotos = function(){

    if($scope.identification){
        flng = angular.copy($scope.identification.following);
        flng.push($scope.identification.username);
        var data = {username: $scope.identification.username, token: $scope.identification.token, following: flng}
    //IDENTIFICATION HAS ALL THE INFO.
    $http.get('/users/getphotos', data).success(function(response){
        $scope.photos = response;
    });
    }
}
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the server side, but I see two problems in the angular code. You cannot pass a body when doing an `HTTP GET` request. Try to pass any necessary data through the url.

Also, the actual data that is returned, will be in `response.data`. Do something like this:

```
var urlData = ""; //add any url data here, by converting 'data' into url params
$http.get('/users/getphotos/' + urlData).then(function(response){
    $scope.photos = response.data;
});
```

For constructing the urlData, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object) question.

Of course, you will have to adjust the server so it reads the data from the url, rather than from the body.

Comment: This was it. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the Content-Type in request request header, is that `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or other. Every content type have to be treated differently. If you use expressjs, try using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to handle request with `multipart-form` content type, I usually use it in my application.

Answer (score 1):

$http doesn't take a 2nd parameter for a data object in GET method. However, $http does accept a data object as the 2nd parameter in POST method.

You'll need pass it as the params property of the config object and access it in your req.query in node:

$http.get('enter/your/url/', { params: data})