# how can I convert object to raw text?

Tags: node.js, requestjs

I need to send a request. If I have copied this request and executed on postman and it works. Postman is sending it as a `raw`. Is there anyway that I can convert my formData object to `raw`?

I tried to use the lib `npm i form-urlencoded` and `encodeURI` and both didnt work.

I need to convert object to `raw type`. How can I do it?

Comment: i think we have a option in postman to see the data as the raw data..

Comment: The problem is converting the object to raw type or to make the request? Because there are different things, if it is on request show us the `content-type` of the request.

Comment: The problem is to convert object to raw type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `raw` content-type.

I just tested the `raw` option in postman and send to a dummy `netcat` server.

The request arrived with `Content-Type: text/plain;`

---

If you need to send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then edit your object with following function example ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object/1714899#1714899)):

```
serialize = function(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for (var p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join("&");
}
```

Comment: I also tried to use `JSON.stringify` but its does not convert to raw ):

Comment: where are you sending the request and what content-type did you specify?

Comment: the content type in the header should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` . I copie this request and import in postman, when I run there it works and it says that it have to be send as a raw