# How to turn JavaScript object to restful GET params to attach at the end of API URL?

Tags: javascript, rest

For example, givent this JSON object:

```
{
    name: 'Tony',
    age: '20',
    birthday: '20180101',
}
```

How can I turn it as parameters to attach to the end of a restful GET API URL like this?

> /API/data?name=Tony&age=20&birthday=20180101

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query-string encoding of a Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`jQuery`.`param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) function:

```js
var object = {
  name: 'Tony',
  age: '20',
  birthday: '20180101',
};
console.log($.param(object));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```