# Send PHP POST using Javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My data is not inserting into database, I get a blank response from the console log and network. I'm kinda lost my javascript source code is mix with other stack overflow answers as well as my PHP code.

```
<form id="requestForm">
    <input type="text" name="fName" id="name">
    <input type="text" name="fAddress" id="address">
    <input type="text" name="fComment" id="comment">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="nameSubmit">
</form>

<script>
        document.querySelector('#requestForm').addEventListener('submit', postRequest);

        function postRequest(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            const params = {

                fName: document.querySelector('#name').value,
                fAddress: document.querySelector('#address').value,
                fComment: document.querySelector('#comment').value,

            };
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'addRequest.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onload = function(){
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
            xhr.send(params);
        } 
    </script>
</body>
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
require_once 'Database.php';

var_dump($_POST); // returns `array(0) {}`

    if (isset($_POST['nameSubmit'])) {
var_dump($_POST); // shows no response    
        $r = $_POST['fName'];
        $o = $_POST['fAddress'];
        $p = $_POST['fComment'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO user_request(name, address, comment) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $insert = $stmt->execute([$r, $o, $p]);

        if($insert){
            echo 'Success';
        }else{
            echo 'Error';
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to call `prepare()` first

Comment: I think `$_POST['nameSubmit']` is not defined, because you don't send it to the server, and therefore the code inside the if statement never gets executed. What does `var_dump($_POST)` return?

Comment: Could this be a problem having the params as `const` ?

Comment: You should open the browser debugger, network panel and check what happen: check if parameters are passed to the php page and check the resulto the php page

Comment: No defining params as const isn't the issue. The issue is as TK says there isn't a variable `nameSubmit` being passed to the server. More than likely the php code was taken from a form submit example where the submit button had name "nameSubmit".

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` returns `array(0) {}`

Comment: Where did you put that line? Edit your question with what you have tried and the output of a `var_dump()` you can write as a comment in your code.

Comment: I put it before the `if(isset)` line.. and when I put it after the `if(isset)` it does not show any response. 
Edit: edit my answer in PHP part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the post parameter `nameSubmit` does not exsist.
Use the `var_dump()` function for dump all `$_POST`
From my prespective, the only parameter given was

- fName
- fAddress
- fComment

Why not check for request method instead?
This is better than checking if a variable exsisted or not.
You can do the checks for required parameter later after you're sure this is a POST request.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    // Do whatever you want when POST request came in
}
```

UPDATE :
Here is the answer you wanted!

```
<form id="requestForm">
    <input type="text" name="fName" id="name">
    <input type="text" name="fAddress" id="address">
    <input type="text" name="fComment" id="comment">

    <button onclick="sendData();" type="button">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="testdiv"></div>

    <script>

      function sendData(){
          var data = new FormData();
          data.append('fName', document.getElementById("name").value);
          data.append('fAddress', document.getElementById("address").value);
          data.append('fComment', document.getElementById("comment").value);

          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', 'test.php', true);
          xhr.onload = function () {
            if(xhr.status !== 200){
              // Server does not return HTTP 200 (OK) response.
              // Whatever you wanted to do when server responded with another code than 200 (OK)
              return; // return is important because the code below is NOT executed if the response is other than HTTP 200 (OK)
            }
            // Whatever you wanted to do when server responded with HTTP 200 (OK)
            // I've added a DIV with id of testdiv to show the result there
            document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          };
          xhr.send(data);
      }

    </script>
</body>
```

The PHP code :

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    var_dump($_POST);
}else{
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
}

?>
```

To add another field, add another `data.append` function below `data` var.
The submit button MUST BE CLICKED. To allow the use of enter, add an event listener for it!.
What it looks like on my end : https://image.ibb.co/gfSHZK/image.png
Hope this is the answer you wanted.

Comment: Asking for clarification : Why is this down voted? 

Comment: I get an error in PHP saying `Undefined index: fName` and `Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs`
and another
`C:\xampp\htdocs\: PDOStatement->execute(Array)`

Comment: Hi, Have you tried to do a `var_dump()` on `$_POST` as I mentioned above?

Comment: @thisisnotwakanda, sorry for my previous response. I've tested your code with var_dump and it returns an empty array... Please check my updated answer as this is definitely what you're looking for. (Tested on localhost with PHP 7.1).

Comment: @thisisnotwakanda Asking for clarification : Is this issue resolved?

Comment: @thisisnotwakanda Glad to hear that :), please upvote the answers back, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1.) Params not sent properly/at all because lack of [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object). When you use form content-type your params object need to be in a particular format `name=value&name2=value2`. So to facilitate that you need to transform your ojbect using something like:

```
function getReadyToSend(object) {
    var objList = [];
    for (var prop in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            objList.push(encodeURI(prop + '=' + object[prop]));
        }
    }
    return objList.join("&");
}
```

So your sending becomes: `xhr.send(getReadyToSend(params));`

2) Your php is expecting the submit button to be sent. `if (isset($_POST['nameSubmit'])) {`
You don't have a variable being sent called `nameSubmit` you can fix this by either including it or check that each variable is set instead. I would suggest the latter that way you can error handle should 1 or more are not passed.

Suggestion: Update your onload to check status:

```
if (xhr.status === 200)
{
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
else if(xhr.status !== 200)
{
    console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of ', xhr.status);
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qofrhemp/1/, open network tab and inspect the call you will now see the params in form data for the call that fires when submit clicked.

Comment: Didn't I include the `nameSubmit` when i put it like this? `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="nameSubmit">`. Thank you for your input sir, your solution seems advanced for me, but for now I'll accept @PlanetCloud's answer and  I'll definitely try your solution later.

Comment: You are doing an ajax call not a form submit. It's not in your params list that you explicitly send to the server.