# Is there a simple way to convert a complex JS object to query params?

Tags: javascript, arrays, query-string

I have a JS object with nested arrays, take this one for example:

```
{
   array: [
    {
        name: 'test-1'
    },
    {
        name: 'test-2'
    }
   ]
   simpleParam: 1,
   complexParam: {
    attribute: 2
   }
}
```

I need to convert it to query params because the API I'm consuming needs to read them in the following format:

"array[0].name='test-1'&array[1].name='test-2'&simpleParam=1&complexParam.attribute=2"

I'd like to know if there's a simple way to do this like JSON.stringify() which in this case does not fit my needs or if I'd need to write my own generic algorithm to do this transformation.

**EDIT**
I'd like to use plain JS and it's important to notice that there'd be arrays in the object I want to format

Comment: You can probably use some sort of library to compress this. But there is no built-in generic way to do what you want.

Comment: I know this is picky, but that's not JSON. Did you mean "javascript object" instead?

Comment: JSON is always a *string*.  You have a JS object literal, not JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query-string encoding of a Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @evolutionxbox you're right, I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from a [class](https://gist.github.com/Pamblam/bf68aad34502bb71bcb8faf6bc5a993e) I wrote for something else:

```js
var data = {
  array: [{
      name: 'test-1'
    },
    {
      name: 'test-2'
    }
  ],
  simpleParam: 1,
  complexParam: {
    attribute: 2
  }
};

var urlstring = stringifyObject(data);

console.log(urlstring);
console.log(decodeURIComponent(urlstring));

/**
 * Provided an object, it will convert it to a query string
 * @param data object to convert
 * @returns query string
 */
function stringifyObject(data) {
  var value, key, tmp = [];
  const encodeFunc = data => encodeURIComponent('' + data).replace(/!/g, '%21')
    .replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29')
    .replace(/\*/g, '%2A').replace(/%20/g, '+');
  const _hbqHelper = (key, val) => {
    var k, tmp = [];
    if (val === true) val = '1';
    else if (val === false) val = '0';
    if (val !== null) {
      if (typeof val === 'object') {
        for (k in val)
          if (val[k] !== null)
            tmp.push(_hbqHelper(key + '[' + k + ']', val[k], '&'));
        return tmp.join('&');
      } else if (typeof val !== 'function') return encodeFunc(key) + '=' + encodeFunc(val);
      else return false;
    } else return '';
  };
  for (key in data) {
    value = data[key];
    var query = _hbqHelper(key, value, '&');
    if (query === false) continue;
    if (query !== '') tmp.push(query)
  }
  return tmp.join('&');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this with `jQuery.param()` and `decodeURI()` hoping the output is what you're looking for.

```
var myObj = {
   array: [
    {
        name: 'test-1'
    },
    {
        name: 'test-2'
    }
   ],
   simpleParam: 1,
   complexParam: {
    attribute: 2
   }
};

console.log(decodeURI($.param(myObj)));
// array[0][name]=test-1&array[1][name]=test-2&simpleParam=1&complexParam[attribute]=2
```

Comment: If it's a duplicate, you are supposed to flag it as such.

Comment: I edited it to stress the fact that there are arrays inside the object, so the answer to the duplicated one doesn't completely apply though it's true they're similar

Comment: don't provide jquery answers to questions that aren't marked jquery.