# Jest test is not passing through any parameters (becomes 'undefined')

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, supertest

**EDIT:** The variable `username` becomes `undefined` for some reason. I tried passing other variables too, but none of them appear as they should with `console.log()`.

I have a jest file *("index.test.js")* for testing my API:

```
'use strict';

const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('./index');

describe('Test login', () => {
  test('POST /login', () => {
        return request(app)
             .post('/login')
             .send({username: 'preset1'})  //suggestion by @acincognito
             .expect(301)

    });

});
```

and a corresponding POST route in my nodejs file *("index.js")*:

```
...

function contains(arr, key, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i][key] === val) {
            return true
        }; 
    }
    return false;
}

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      var username = req.body.username;
      const data = await readFile("results.json");
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      if (contains(json, "name", username) === true){

         ...

         return res.redirect(301,"/");
       } else {
         return res.redirect(401,"/");
       }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.redirect("/");
    }
});
```

JSON file *("results.json")* has the following format:

```
[
  {"name":"preset1","otherstuff":[]},
  ...
  {"name":"preset5","otherstuff":[]}
]
```

I am getting the error message :

`expected 301 "Moved Permanently", got 401 "Unauthorized"`

**NOTE:** When I run the code manually on a local server, everything works as it should which seems to contradict the output of the test.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `console.log(json)` to your `app.post` function to see what gets parsed.

After looking at the docs for `supertest`: apparently `.set('username','preset1')` is for setting headers in your request, but according to your `app.post` `username` is inside the request's body, therefore try `.send({username: 'preset1'})` .

Comment: `console.log(json)` gives the same JSON file output as mentioned in my question. Unfortunately, `.send({username: 'preset1'})` is still giving the same error.

Comment: Well, then try to log `username`, might be `undefined`.

Comment: You're right, `username` is not defined. But, why would `username` still be undefined if I'm sending it via jest? (Please correct me if my ideas of how jest works are wrong as I am very new to testing).

Comment: I tried passing other variables too, but none of them appear as they should with `console.log()`.

Comment: Apparently the body isnt set correctly. Yous should take a look at the documentation for `supertest` to find out, what went wrong/which method to use to set the body.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to encode a Javascript Object into a string.

```
function serialize(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).map(k => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[k])}`).join('&');
}

// Code from : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object
```

Instead of:

```
.send({username: 'preset1'})
```

Replace with:

```
.send(serialize({username: 'preset1'}))
```

**Edit:** This did not work for all parameters.