# Getting HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type during authorization in the Spotify API

Tags: javascript, api, rest, express, axios

I want to access the Spotify web API using the "Client Credentials Flow" as mentioned [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow). I tried to access it using some tutorial mention [here](https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples), but couldn't follow it because it uses the request library in node which has now been deprecated so, I tried using axios in it's place and keep getting the Status Code 415 error in the browser console. I'm trying to create a side project using this API for practice because I'm a beginner. I've done this using NodeJS and the normal browser console(i have used the code for browser console here) and i had axios and express libraries installed(while using node).

```js
const client_id = '**redacted**';
const client_secret = '**redacted**';

const res = axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${client_id}` + ':' + `${client_secret}`),
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
  }
});

console.log(res)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AXIOS DOC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spotify's API requires you to encode the body of POST request in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. To do this with axios you need to use other library or make `serialize()` function on your own (I used `serialize(obj)` function [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/1330105)).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AXIOS DOC</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const client_id = '**redacted**';
        const client_secret = '**redacted**';

        const serialize = function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for (var p in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                }
            }
            return str.join("&");
        }

        axios
            .post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                serialize({
                    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
                }), {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret),
                }
            })
            .then(res => console.log(res.data.access_token))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The other solution is to simply use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library that serializes data automatically.

Also, be aware of making requests using *Client Credential* grant type from the client-side. This way you expose your `client_secret` and give other people a way to impersonate your application.

*Client Credential* grant type should be used only on the server-side, where you can be sure that your `client_secret` doesn't get exposed.

If you want to safety authenticate users on the client-side use *Authorization Code With PKCE* (better) or *Implicit* grant type.

Comment: Hi macborowy, I used the code which you gave above and it just returned a status code 400.
Thanks for making the changes needed to my question.
I had one question i wanted to ask you, I want to create a web app in which people can search for 2 artist or songs side by side and compare how good they have done in numbers or other criteria, so according to you which grant type should i go?

Comment: Check if your `client_id` and `client_secret` are correct and compare them with data on Spotify's page.

Comment: If you have backend for your application then use _Authorization Code_ or _Client Credentials_. If it is a mobile app then _Authorization Code with PKCE_. And, if it is SPA use _Implicit_ (or _Authorization Code with PKCE_). In your code, you make requests from the client-side so it is similar to the SPA case.

Comment: Thanks macborowy, It worked now it must have been mistake in my part. 

what does SPA stand for?

Comment: SPA stands for [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto a recent code snippet that is using axios to make the POST request instead of the request library. I just tried it and was able to receive an access token! Let me know if you have any questions. Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/donstefani/70ef1069d4eab7f2339359526563aab2). Be sure to install the qs package.

The code looks something like this:

```
// Headers object.
const headers = {
 headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  auth: {
    username: client_id,
    password: client_secret,
  },
};

// Data object.
const data = {
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
};

// Make the request using the URL, query string, data, and headers.
const res = axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', qs.stringify(data), headers);

// Retrieve the access token from the response.
const access_token = res.data.access_token;
```

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks for sharing the link, that did trick for me because using your code without putting it inside an async function and without try and catch block, like in the link that you mentioned was just simply giving this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of undefined at Object.". I really appreciate you helping, Thanks!

Comment: Hello Shubhank92! No problemo! Glad I could help. Yeah sorry, I forgot to mention you will need to put this into an async code block and use the await keyword or and the .then() and .catch() promise chains onto the axios.post() call. Glad I could help!