# How to have an empty string as a parameter value in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, http, dart

Suppose you want to send an empty search query to an API. For example:

> [https://api.example.com/search?query=''](https://api.example.com/search?query=%27%27)

In Dart, it makes sense to create this URI with:

```
final uri = Uri.https('api.example.com', 'search', {'query': ''});
```

But if you try to print this out: `print(uri);` you will see:

> https://api.example.com/search?query

My current workaround is to wrap double-quotes inside single-quotes (or other way around):

```
final uri = Uri.https('api.example.com', 'search', {'query': '""'});
```

which produces this URI:

> https://api.example.com/search?query=%22%22

Not a big deal. But still this behavior surprised me as a bit illogical. Who would want to send only a parameter name and not its value? Is it a problem of http library or am I missing something here? Is it the intended behavior and actually serves a purpose?

Comment: What if you query only with `{'query': '"'}`?

Comment: As I said, `{'query': '""'}` works. I don't understand your code. Sending one double-quote as the query value? I tried it and server ignored it.

Comment: this is not an error, the encoded value of "" is %22%22

Comment: This in irrelevant to the question. Question is: why `{'query': ''}` doesn't do the expected behavior, i.e. just putting an empty string as the value of `query` in the final URL.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same use case too. Looked around and ended up with this with some inspiration from the [plain javascript implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

```
void main() {
  String fullURL = 'http://api.example.com/search';
  Object queryParameters = {'query': '', 'colour': 'green', 'name': ''};

  String queryString = getQueryString(queryParameters);
  fullURL += '?' + queryString;
  print(fullURL); // http://api.example.com/search?query=&colour=green&name=
}

getQueryString(object) {
    var str = [];
    object.forEach(
      (k, v) => str.add(Uri.encodeComponent(k) + "=" + Uri.encodeComponent(v)),
    );
    return str.join("&");
}
```

Comment: This is too much work. Just put a pair of double-quotes inside inside each ' ' .