# How to pass values and link next page throw href tag in pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In pug file i have values in "n" i have to pass the values throw the href tag to next page. How to change in href tag. it should be a link not a button.

```
 a(Class=`change_pasword` onclick=`next('${n}')`) Change Password  
            script.
              function next(parmas) {
                window.location.href = `/update_password?user_details=${parmas}`
              }
```

How to change the code to href?

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a regular link if you [convert the js object to a query string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/5351721) within Pug first.

```
- const serialize(obj) { ... } // use the formula from the linked answer
a.change_password(href=`/update_password?user_details=${serialize(n)}`) Change Password
```

Comment: Cannot pass the values @Sean

Comment: Which values, @FreddyChris?

Comment: ${n} in n i have the values to be passed @Sean

Comment: @FreddyChris what is `n`, an object? or array?

Comment: It is an object @Sean