# Map complex javascript objects to formulate a request with content type of x-www- form-urlencoded in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, x-www-form-urlencoded

I want to convert complex request objects to queryString like format for posting the formData with content type as x-www- form-urlencoded .
My object would be of format

```
const obj= {
  "Employee": {
    "Id": 123,
    "Settings": {
      "StartOfDayType": [
        1
      ],
      "EndOfDayType": [
        2
      ],
      "workSettings": {
        "WorkStartTime": "{\"Ticks\":288000000000,\"Days\":0,\"Hours\":8,\"Milliseconds\":0,\"Minutes\":0,\"Seconds\":0,\"TotalDays\":0.33333333333333331,\"TotalHours\":8,\"TotalMilliseconds\":28800000,\"TotalMinutes\":480,\"TotalSeconds\":28800}",
        "WorkEndTime": "{\"Ticks\":648000000000,\"Days\":0,\"Hours\":18,\"Milliseconds\":0,\"Minutes\":0,\"Seconds\":0,\"TotalDays\":0.75,\"TotalHours\":18,\"TotalMilliseconds\":64800000,\"TotalMinutes\":1080,\"TotalSeconds\":64800}",
        
      },
      "StartLocation": {
        "Latitude": 0.0,
        "Longitude": 0.0
      },
      "StartAddr": null,
      "EndLocation": {
        "Latitude": 0.0,
        "Longitude": 0.0
      },
      "EndAddr": null
    }
  }
}
```

I want to convert this to QueryString like format , in jquery we have $.param can't use it, but is there anything similar we can achieve the same in typescript.
tries almost everything upon googling , but none of them converting complex objects .
Any help would be much appreciated .
Thank you

Comment: Please don't close this question ,instead please suggest what more information to be provided

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: You _can_ install jQuery and use it in TypeScript for this, even in Angular application.

Comment: @Lazar I am looking for another alternative solutions

Comment: If jQuery would do what you want, but you don't want to use jQuery, the next logical thing to do is to open up their source code and check out _how_ they're doing it.