# NextJS rewrites with wildcard query string params

Tags: next.js, url-rewriting, query-string

I am having a bit of an issue: I am trying to setup a rewrite in NextJS that will automatically send on the query string to the destination. However, the only examples I can find are with named params. In this case there could be any number of params, so I need a way of making a wildcard (I assume this will be possible?)

What I am looking to do is the following:

```
/results?param1=a&param2=b... => https://www.somedomain.com/results?param1=a&param2=b...
or
/results?house=red&car=blue&money=none => https://www.somedomain.com/results??house=red&car=blue&money=none
```

```
rewrites() {
    return [ 
      {
        source:'/results?:params*',
        destination:'https://www.somedomain.com/results?:params*'
      },
```

Of course this doesn't work, so I looked into `has` but I cannot workout how to make it work without names params

```
       {
          source: '/some-page',
          destination: '/somewhere-else',
          has: [{ type: 'query', key: 'overrideMe' }],
        },
```

Comment: A simple rewrite will, by default, pass any query params that the source URL may have. Just do `{ source: '/results', destination: 'https://www.somedomain.com/results' }`.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like a total ding dong. Why didn't I try that? :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, a rewrite will pass through any query params that the source URL may have.

In your case, you can simply have the following rewrite rule. All query params will be forwarded through the destination URL.

```js
rewrites() {
  return [ 
    { 
      source: '/results', 
      destination: 'https://www.somedomain.com/results' 
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard page like this below. What I did is when the router is initialized in a `useEffect` hook it gets the query (object) and then use the `objectToQueryString` function to turn it back into a url encoded string, then used the `router` to redirect to the other page

```
// /pages/some-page.jsx
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const objectToQueryString = (initialObj) => {
    const reducer = (obj, parentPrefix = null) => (prev, key) => {
        const val = obj[key];
        key = encodeURIComponent(key);
        const prefix = parentPrefix ? `${parentPrefix}[${key}]` : key;

        if (val == null || typeof val === 'function') {
            prev.push(`${prefix}=`);
            return prev;
        }

        if (['number', 'boolean', 'string'].includes(typeof val)) {
            prev.push(`${prefix}=${encodeURIComponent(val)}`);
            return prev;
        }

        prev.push(Object.keys(val).reduce(reducer(val, prefix), []).join('&'));
        return prev;
    };

    return Object.keys(initialObj).reduce(reducer(initialObj), []).join('&');
};

const Results = () => {
    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
        const query = router.query
        router.replace(`https://www.somedomain.com/results?${objectToQueryString(query)}`)
    }, [router])

    return <></>

}
export default Results
```

I used the `objectToQueryString` based on [Query-string encoding of a Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I have done something similar already, bit I don't really want to redirect, I was the re-write the URL so it all happens within the existing  domain. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this behavior, you need to capture the value of the query-parameter like this:

```js
rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/some-page",
      has: [{ type: "query", key: "override_me", value: "(?<override>.*)" }],
      destination: "/somewhere-else?override_me=:override",
    },
  ];
}
```