# How to convert a type to query string?

Tags: typescript

I'm using Typescript.

I have a type defined like this:

```js
export type SearchStoresParameters = {
    storeCategory : string;
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
}
```

And I'm trying to convert above type object to a query string.

```js
export const searchStores = async (searchStoresParameters : SearchStoresParameters ) => {
    var queryString = Object.keys(searchStoresParameters).map((key) => {
        return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(searchStoresParameters[key])
    }).join('&');
    const searchStoresApi = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_SERVICE_API + "/stores?" + queryString;
    const res = await fetch(
        searchStoresApi,
    );
    const response = await res.json();
}
```

However, above code shows error :

```
(parameter) searchStoresParameters: SearchStoresParameters
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'SearchStoresParameters'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'SearchStoresParameters'.ts(7053)
```

What's the best way to convert a typescript type to query string?

Comment: There are also answers here although they are quite ancient and don't use good techniques IMO https://stackoverflow.com/q/1714786/10873797

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would advise using the [built-in `URLSearchParams` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) as it was built to performantly serialize/deserialize search param data.  Here is an example program of how you would use it:

```
const data = { firstName: "Jon", lastName: "Doe" };
console.log(new URLSearchParams(data).toString()); // "firstName=Jon&lastName=Doe"
```

It also encodes the text as required for URLs:

```
console.log(new URLSearchParams({ foo: "Can it handle weird text?" }).toString()); // "foo=Can+it+handle+weird+text%3F"
```

Also, if you are worried about support, consult [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/urlsearchparams) and use [a polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill) if you want to still use it.  Anyways, here is your code adapted to use this Web API:

```
export const searchStores = async (searchStoresParameters : SearchStoresParameters ) => {
    var queryString = new URLSearchParams(searchStoresParameters).toString();
    const searchStoresApi = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_SERVICE_API + "/stores?" + queryString;
    const res = await fetch(
        searchStoresApi,
    );
    const response = await res.json();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`searchStoresParameters[key]` is with a dynamic key, so you need to define your type with a dynamic key too.

```
export type SearchStoresParameters = {
    storeCategory : string;
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    [key: string]: number | string;
}
```

I think you are trying to parse an object to query strings, so you also can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) which is much simpler

```
const queryString = new URLSearchParams(searchStoresParameters).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am converted type to query string like this:

```
 var queryString = Object.keys(params).map(key => key + '=' + params[key as keyof IChatAsk]).join('&');
```

the type defined like this:

```
export type ChatAsk = {
    prompt: string;
    cid: number;
}
```