# How to convert from object to query string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert values to query string.

```js
var obj = {
  param1: 'test',
  param2: true,
}

var str = "";

for (var key in obj) {
  if (str != "") {
    str += "&";
  }
  str += key + "=" + obj[key];
}

console.log(str);
```

Expected query string would be like this: `test=true`.

Comment: btw why use " " in query string since it will always be a string when capturng from server side. also the true will also be a string "true" when caught in server

Comment: Basically, I want to get object values to query string if it's bolean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query-string encoding of a Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

Comment: No, I actually want to get like from  {
  param1: 'test',
  param2: true,
} to value "test=true"

Comment: This seem like an x/y problem. _Why_ does `NO` have to be in quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be much easier if you would use objects as intended but:

```js
const obj = {
  param1: 'test',
  param2: 'true',
  param3: 'test2',
  param4: 'NO',
}

const entries = Object.values(obj)

const trueObj = {}
for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i += 2) {
  trueObj[entries[i]] = entries[i + 1]
}

const params = new URLSearchParams(trueObj)

const queryString = params.toString()

console.log(queryString)
```

Comment: my Expected result would be : test=true&test2="NO"

Comment: How do you distinguish which one should be wrapped in `""` if both types are string?

Why your object don't look like this: `{ test: true, test2: 'NO' }`

Comment: one would be string and other would-be bolean

Comment: In your questions both are string, `true` in javascript is written without quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can use back ticks to insert the quote. You will however, have to write a bit of extra logic in you obj variable to determine which parameters should be passed as a string or just the value.

```js
const string = `"NO"`;
console.log(string)
```