# Better way to create query string dynamically

Tags: javascript, string, query-string

I'm getting a query params object that may look like this:

```
const queryParams = { status: 'Online', name: 'Jeff', age: '35' }
```

I need to create a query params string out of it,

Example return value would be:

```
?status=Online&name=Jeff&age=35&
```

I wrote this function:

```
const getParams = (queryParams) => {
  let str = '?'
  for (key in queryParams) {
  if (queryParams[key]) {
    str+= `${key}=${queryParams[key]}&`
   }
  }
  return str
};
```

Is there a shorter/better way to do it than this function?

Comment: Note the second answer in the duplicate is the modern solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53171438/519413

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Although your link links to the answer you mention, which answer is second depends upon the individual users currently selected sort order.

Comment: That's true. I assumed the default sort order of highest scoring, but I also made sure to link directly to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const queryParams = { status: 'Online', name: 'Jeff', age: '35' };

function buildQueryString(params) {
  const queryString = Object.entries(params)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
    .join('&');
  return queryString;
}

const queryString = buildQueryString(queryParams);
```