# AngularJs file download pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a rest service for file download, I test and it works if I just copy paste the url to addres bar in browser I can see the browser pop up window ask me to save the file:

```
myaddress/assets/csvreport
```

BUT using AngularJs with a download button, there  is no pop up window if I use it like this;

```
       $scope.downloadAssets = function () {
         $http({
               method: 'GET',
               url: '/assets/csvreport',
               params: criteria
        })
```

I call this method from my html like this;

```
 <input ng-click="downloadAssets()" value="Download" type="submit">
```

This only returns the string in response and I can not see any browser file save pop-up

Any Ideas? It needs to work on IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$http` is not for downloading file.  It's for calling AJAX things. You can just redirect the page to that url:

```
$scope.downloadAssets = function () {
  var querystring = buildQueryString( criteria )
  window.location = '/assets/csvreport?' + querystring;
}
```

You can find the `buildQueryString` function here : 
[How to build query string with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316781/how-to-build-query-string-with-javascript);

Comment: tnx and how can I add my paremeters, I think this will also change how I handle the params in the backend as well?

Comment: I added some code to show you how to add parameter, And you dont have to change on the server side, It's work the same way as before.

Comment: can I add my authentication token to header?