# Facebook share button - dynamic website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

So I have this website that has 3 pages but instead of sending the user to the new page i hide the previous one and display the new one. On addition the elements in the new page are generated at the moment he clicks to navigate to the new page, therefore the url is always `"www.example.com/#"` so if the user tries to share the website it will share the homepage. is there a way to trace his steps and generate a certain link to link at his current page?

Comment: An option would be to add a querystring to your url when generating the new page, allowing dynamic generation of your Facebook sharebutton.

Comment: any tutorials/examples to point me to? :D Am a complete beginner, do I add them with javascript/php?

Comment: Googling would be a good start for you!

Comment: lol I did google before my comment and it felt like diving in a sea of information but much of it would be useless and time consuming :D

Comment: Learning something is timeconsuming and if you really want to learn and do something you actually have to but time in it. Try this: https://suite.io/guy-lecky-thompson/2m4a21g

Comment: thank you :), I agree but with so much information if you can have a filter (in this case you) so you can get the information sooner/better why not use it :D

Comment: All I did was googling. Anyways, good luck!

Comment: helpful article, I managed to get the current url and append it, but how do I assign it to the page I want eg: if you put `www.example.com/#page3` to your browser to take you to the third page

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316781/how-to-build-query-string-with-javascript