# IsPostBack is always True when we Submit the form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using below code in .js file using asp.net from page1.aspx page

Form1.action = "testpage.aspx";
Form1.submit();

When the form is submitted the IsPostBack is always True when it's redirected to "textpage.aspx"

Is there any things which i am missing here?

Comment: This seems like correct behaviour. You're submitting (posting) the form, so IsPostBack *should* be true.

Answer (score 1):

You are submitting a form. That's what postback exactly is.

Redirect would be e.g.:

```
window.location.href = 'testpage.aspx';
```

**EDIT:**
It's not clear from your post whether the testpage.aspx is the same page as the one containing the submitted form. If you want to avoid postback then you'll have to [build a querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316781/how-to-build-query-string-with-javascript), attach it to the URL and perform a redirect. Then you can access the parameters using [`Request.Params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The Problem using window.location.href is there are many hidden and form variable which i need in the next redirected page. Which i will not be getting if i use window.location.href.