# React js - axios calls - url maker to pass array params

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, api

I am developing a website in reactjs -- and the server side api - seems to want to take array params like this. --

```
"order_by[0]=director_first_name asc&order_by[1]=trading_name&filter_by[0]=trading_name like a%&filter_by[1]=star_rating > 1&filter_by[2]=number_of_employees > 1"
```

but I am unsure if I need to create a string that looks like this - or if its a case of building the array in javascript then doing a JSON.parse() before it gets pushed into the axios call?

--

I've tried creating an array of strings like this

```
let orderBy = []
orderBy.push("director_first_name asc");
orderBy.push("trading_name");
```

then would I just wrap around a JSON.Parse when attaching it to the url string?

-- tried this but this hasn't worked
https://jsfiddle.net/nk5Ly6hf/1/

====
would something like this work -- but then the arrays haven't been given pointers - https://jsfiddle.net/nk5Ly6hf/3/  aka  filter_by[0], filter_by[1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Comment: no - I need to create the string in javascript - and deliver it to the backend in that manner -

Comment: something like this - but this hasn't worked - https://jsfiddle.net/nk5Ly6hf/1/

Comment: Ah I understand, try this post: (how to build query string with javascript)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316781/how-to-build-query-string-with-javascript/34209399#34209399]

Comment: I've tried two methods from there - no luck

Comment: would something like this work -- but then the arrays haven't been given pointers - https://jsfiddle.net/nk5Ly6hf/3/

Answer (score 0):

in the end I just built a function to create a string,

```
  flatArrayToString(key, arr){
      let output = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        output += "&"+key+"["+i+"]="+arr[i];
      }

      return output;
  }
```