# constructing url with base url strips the path in base url

Tags: javascript, url

When I try to construct a `url` in JavaScript using `new URL(url, base)`, it strips the pathname in `base`

below is my code

```js
const getUrl = () => {
  const ids = ["1","2","3"];
  const url = new URL("/items", "https://example.com/v1");
  url.searchParams.set("id", ids?.toString() ?? "");
  
  return url.toString();
};

console.log(getUrl());
// https://example.com/items?id=1%2C2%2C3
```

I need the output to be: `https://example.com/v1/items?id=1%2C2%2C3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build query string with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316781/how-to-build-query-string-with-javascript)

Comment: No, I have already solved the query string part of the problem

Comment: The behavior you're describing is just how [the API works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#examples).

Comment: If you want `["1","2","3"]` url encoded then you'll need to do that separately. this is a completely non standard way of sending arrays in a query string. So you'll have to write that yourself. I'd suggest you actually use a POST and JSON encoding, not this. Querystring is only for simple key value pairs not objects or arrays.

Comment: A leading slash in a relative URL _always_ refers to the domain root. You would actually need `new URL("items", "https://example.com/v1/")` here.

Comment: `v1` is part of the `url`, use :`new URL("/v1/items", "https://example.com/");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
const url = new URL("/items", "https://example.com/v1");
```

You can use

```
const url = new URL("https://example.com/v1"+"/items");
```

const url = new URL(path, base)

here base will ignore all the sub path, and it will construct your URL by using only the base path ie domain (https://example.com)