# %26 and %3d shown up in html query instead of & and =

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to generate the following
`deviceSearch?q=4100&origin=pdp`

instead I am seeing
`deviceSearch?q=4100%26origin%3Dpdp`

Googling this problem it seems I cannot do this.
I tried the following that did not work

```
    url.searchParams.set('q', item.selectionText);
    url.searchParams.append(name: origin, value: pdp);
```

I tried joining the text which did not work.

```
url.searchParams.set('q', item.selectionText.concat('&origin=pdp'));
```

I also tried using escape code '\' before those characters.  I assume I am missing something in addition to any real knowledge of javascript.

Comment: You see it where? This URL will work properly and back-end will see all parameters (if setup properly). And what you see is URL encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `set` again, same way you are setting the `q` parameter. `&` symbol is added by the `URLSeachParams` class itself.

```js
url.searchParams.set('q', item.selectionText);
url.searchParams.set('origin', 'pdp');
```

You can also use `.append`, the syntax would be the same:

```js
url.searchParams.append('origin', 'pdp');
```

But that might not be what you're trying to do. Difference is that `set` will override the value if you try set the *same* parameter twice, and `append` will let add the same parameter multiple times.

```js
url.searchParams.set('foo', '1');
url.searchParams.set('foo', '2');
// results in '?foo=2

url.searchParams.append('foo', '1');
url.searchParams.append('foo', '2');
// results in ?foo=1&foo=2
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  I had found the following  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316781/how-to-build-query-string-with-javascript but you got it.  I am going to leave my question even with the "-1" as someone else may have the same problem

Comment: I recommend reading docs before jumping to stackoverflow. MDN explains the methods well and has plenty of examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: This worked very nicely.  I have a demo of my app here https://github.com/JStateson/HP_search

Answer (score 1):

Each of these are separate query parameters of the URL string.  You don't manually add the `&` or `=` symbols as they are a result of the parameter definitions.  The `url.searchParams.set` takes the parameter name as the first argument and the value assigned as the second argument. That creates the key value pair or (parameter=value) The `&` is a result of more than one parameter being set with that method.

If you called this method 4 different times you would have this example URL string.

```js
url.searchParams.set('q', '4100');
url.searchParams.set('origin', 'php');
url.searchParams.set('name', 'test');
url.searchParams.set('age', 12);
```

// /deviceSearch?q=4100&origin=php&name=test&age=12