# How do I see the url that I'm using in $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, javascript-debugger

I have the following code snip and am trying to debug it. Is there a way to get the full url string that the .getJSON call is calling?

```
opts = {};
opts['start'] = startdate;
opts['end'] = enddate;
opts['email'] = addresses;
$.getJSON(url_count_string, opts, function(data){
   drawChart(data, chartsData['hourChart']);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried just watching the request with Fiddler?

Comment: Install firebug and check the console?

Comment: `console.log(url_count_string)`?  Or use Chrome's console/Firebug to monitor the XHR request.

Comment: so apparently the query will append opts to the url_count_string. I'm not exactly how it does this, but I would like to see the full URL after it does append it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox w/Firebug - "Net" tab.

Chrome - "Network" tab.

IE9 - "Network" tab.

Safari - "Network" tab.

Opera - Dragonfly "Network" tab.

Answer (score 0):

if your url_count_string is relative & what you want to see if full url, then append url_count_string to current path.

If what you want to see is url with request params appended (x=123&y=456....), try to see XHR Net Panel in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the method is making a GET request, so it must be appending the `data` in the standard way.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111529/create-query-parameters-in-javascript/111545#111545), we can do this:

```
function createGetParams(data) {
  var ret = [];
  for (var d in data) {
    ret.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
  }
  return ret.join("&");
}

var finalURL = url_count_string + '?' + createGetParams(opts);
```

Assuming the `opts` array and `url_count_string` variables are defined as they are in your question.

`finalURL` will be the URL that jQuery is sending the request to.