# How do you pass a javascript array to php through GET?

Tags: php, javascript

I have to pass `amount` and `name` arrays from javascript to a php script via http GET.

```
var amount=new Array();   
amount = document.form_perk.elements["amount[]"];  
var name = document.form_perk.elements["name[]"];
http.open('get', 'perks.php?+obj2url("amount", amount)&obj2url("name", name)');   
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;  
http.send(null);
```

How is this done?

Comment: read more about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX maybe that could help you

Comment: @MrCode: JSON.stringify(amount) could produce the query part if you also replaced `:` and `,` with `=` and `&`.

Comment: Or you could pass the entire JSON string (Ex. `str_json`) as a single query parameter and then do `$arr = json_decode($_GET['str_json'], true);` in the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: It appears the problem is this:

```
http.open('get', 'perks.php?+obj2url("amount", amount)&obj2url("name", name)');
```

Should be:

```
http.open('get', 'perks.php?' + obj2url("amount", amount) + '&' + obj2url("name", name)');
```

ORIGINAL POST:

Use this function (modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111545/888177)):

```
function EncodeQueryData(arr_data, str_prepend) {
   str_prepend = str_prepend || "";
   var ret = [];
   for (var d in arr_data)
       ret.push(encodeURIComponent(str_prepend + d) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(arr_data[d]));
   return ret.join("&");
}

var base_url = "perks.php";
var query_string = EncodeQueryData(amount, "amount") + '&' + EncodeQueryData(name, "name");
window.location = base_url + '?' + query_string;
```

This should give you for example something like this:

`perks.php?amount0=10&amount1=27&name0=john&name1=sally`.

Comment: i got                                                         perks.php?amount0=[object HTMLInputElement]&amount1=[object HTMLInputElement]&amountlength=2&amountitem=function item() {%0A    [native code]%0A}&name0=[object HTMLInputElement]&name1=[object HTMLInputElement]&namelength=2&nameitem=function item() {%0A    [native code]%0A}

Comment: Use for loop first to create your arrays, or use jQuery to get your arrays: `var amount = [];
$('input[name="amount[]"]').each(function(){
    values.push($(this).val());
});`

Comment: Or: `arr_amount = [];
    for (var i=0; i< amount.length; i++) {
     arr_amount[i] = amount[i].value;
 }`.  Then pass `arr_amount` instead of `amount` to EncodeQueryData etc.

Comment: @shilpa: Actually, it looks like you simply have a small mistake: Change `http.open('get', 'perks.php?+obj2url("amount", amount)&obj2url("name", name)');` to this: `http.open('get', 'perks.php?' + obj2url("amount", amount) + '&' + obj2url("name", name)');`

Comment: how to get the first element of the array ...it gives value undefined

Comment: The first element is `amount[0]`. You mean `amount = document.form_perk.elements["amount[]"];` gives `undefined`? Make sure that your HTML form inputs are named like this: `name='amount[]'`, i.e that there are brackets.

Comment: I have done that..but when i entered only 1 value to amount and name field then while redirecting it gives  perks.php?&&amount-length=undefined&name-length=undefined..even if its the first element I should be able to save it .how to do?

Comment: Are you using `obj2url()` or are you using the `EncodeQueryData()` function?

Comment: Try this: `amount = [].concat(amount);` and `name = [].concat(name);` before using them in `obj2url()` or `EncodeQueryData()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply..It worked.I am using EncodeQueryData().As in obj2url() while inspecting in FF(DOM) i get responseText as                                                                Array
(
    [obj2url("amount",_amount)___] => 
    [obj2url("name",_name)__] => 
    [obj2url("pdescrb",_pdescrb)__] => 
    [obj2url("number",_number)__] => 
    [obj2url("estimatedate",_estimatedate)] => 
)