# Finding last iteration in for in loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having following sample code

```
   var obj = { a: {b:1, c:3 }, d :{f:5}}
        var string = "";
        for(var key in obj){
            for(var subkey in obj[key]){
             string += subkey + "="+ obj[key][subkey] + "&";
             //for last iteration "&" should not be added.
         }
    }
   console.log(string);
```

**output is**

```
b=1&c=3&f=5&
```

**Required Output**

```
b=1&c=3&f=5
```

Comment: In this particular case, the easiest thing to do would be to simply take a substring of your output string, to remove the '&'.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, let that to jQuery. Don't compose the URL yourself

Comment: If it is for transmitting parameters and this is the final query string, just leave the `&` at the end. It won´t matter.

Comment: `string += "&"+subkey + "="+ obj[key][subkey];` and at the end do `... string.substring(1)`

Comment: Not a contribution to the question but to your case: are you sure your subkeys are unique (e.g. if subkey b in key a there cannot be a subkey b in key d)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alternative approach would be:

```
var obj = { a: {b:1, c:3 }, d :{f:5}},
  array = [];
for(var key in obj){
  for(var subkey in obj[key]){
    array.push(subkey + "="+ obj[key][subkey]);
  }
}
console.log(array.join('&'));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're creating the query-part of a url, I'd go with the solution provided here:
[How to create query parameters in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111529/create-query-parameters-in-javascript)

If not, just drop the encoding-part :)

Copy of relevant code:

```
// Usage:
//   var data = { 'first name': 'George', 'last name': 'Jetson', 'age': 110 };
//   var querystring = EncodeQueryData(data);
// 
function EncodeQueryData(data)
{
   var ret = [];
   for (var d in data)
      ret.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
   return ret.join("&");
}
```

Comment: You should be able to drop the first encodeURIComponent I should think, unless the field names have non-ascii chars

Answer (score 2):

after for loop you can do like: `string = string.slice(0,-1)`

Comment: Or `string += "&"+subkey + "="+ obj[key][subkey];` and at the end `... string.substring(1)`

Comment: @Christoph sorry I commented correct but answered wrong, for  mplungjan let me think

Comment: @mplungjan sorry :( I didn't understand, `string.substring(1)` will remove first `char` if I am not wrong, please example bit more I am also new learner  web-languages ..

Comment: Yes it will, and I moved the & to the start.

Answer (score 1):

For each iterarion append first `&` except for the first one.

```
var obj = { a: {b:1, c:3 }, d :{f:5}}
var string = "";
for(var key in obj){
   for(var subkey in obj[key]){
      if(string !== "") string += "&";
      string += subkey + "=" + obj[key][subkey];
    }
}
```