# Swift - post to server multiple values

Tags: php, ios, swift, nsurlconnection

I have a function that send two string values "Name and Text" to a server.
When the post method is sent the php file send an email with this two values.

Everything works if I send only one value from my iOS app however, if I try to send two or more value I don't get any email.

The code I am using is:

```
func postToServerFunction() {
    var textFromapp: NSString = sendValueText.text
    var nameFromapp: NSString = sendValueName.text
    println("Button Pressed")
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://example.com//iOS/send_ios.php")!
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
    var bodyData = "data=" + (textFromapp as String) //data to send
    var bodyName = "name=" + (nameFromapp as String) //data to send
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    request.HTTPBody = bodyName.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in
            println(response)

            if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

                if statusCode == 200 {
                    // Yes, Do something. 
                }
            }

    }


}
```

How could I tell the HTTPBody to look at both values?

Answer (score 4):

for Future reference here how I solved it:

```
var bodyData = "data=" + (textFromapp as String) + "&name=" + (nameFromapp as String)
```

any other suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111529/create-query-parameters-in-javascript). Fun(ctional) is the most beautiful.

```
function encodeData(data) {
    return Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
        return [key, data[key]].map(encodeURIComponent).join("=");
    }).join("&");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. but this us for java script I am looking for a solution for Swift