# Window.open() with parameters

Tags: typescript, window, window.open

I am trying to open a url in a new tab with some custom parameters, but the custom parameters never show when opening the page.

Example given: we have a url that already contains parameters. If we use window.open like this it works as intended and opens the url:

```
const myUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spotify.music&hl=nl&gl=US" 

window.open(myUrl, "_blank")
```

But when i try to do something like this it just opens "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spotify.music&hl=nl&gl=US" again and ignores / removes the parameters i added:

```
const customUrl = `${myUrl}&foo=${encodeURIComponent(params!.foo)}&bar=${encodeURIComponent(params!.bar)}`
```

I have gone through numerous topics already but I have not found a solution. I tried with and without the encodeURIComponent, replacing '&' with '&' and also while not using string interpolation. Am i missing something?

Comment: `${myUrl}&foo=${encodeURIComponent(params!.foo)}&bar=${encodeURIComponent(params!.bar)}` is not a properly encoded URL. The first parameter should be separated by `?`. I would advise to use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#examples) instead of manually creating URLs. This way those kind of errors cannot happen. Check out [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73678107/17487348).